raylib c++ rundefined referance to InitWindow and all functions of raylib
c++ compiler: default mingw from sourceforge
code editor: vscode
myFileStructure:
*build/
├── _deps/
│   ├── raylib-build/
│   ├── raylib-src/
│   │   ├── CHANGELOG
│   │   ├── include/
│   │   ├── lib/
│   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   └── README.md
│   └── raylib-tmp/
├── .cmake/
│   └── api/
│       └── v1/
├── cmake_install.cmake
├── CMakeCache.txt
├── CMakeFiles/...morehere
├── compile_commands.json
└── Makefile
CMakeLists.txt
main.cpp*

main.cpp file:
#include "raylib.h"

int main()
{
    // Initialization
    InitWindow(800, 600, "Hello Raylib");
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    // Main game loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose())
    {
        // Update

        // Draw
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
        DrawText("Hello, Raylib!", 190, 200, 20, LIGHTGRAY);
        EndDrawing();
    }

    // De-Initialization
    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.30)
project(myproject)
include(FetchContent)

set(RAYLIB_VERSION 5.0)
FetchContent_Declare(
    raylib
    URL https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/releases/download/5.0/raylib-5.0_win64_mingw-w64.zip
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(raylib)

# Include the raylib headers
include_directories(${raylib_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

# Link the raylib library
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main raylib)

running cmake .. output:
--downloades raylib here--
-- [download 98% complete]
-- [download 99% complete]
-- [download 100% complete]
-- Configuring done (3.7s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/kui c++/main/build

running mingw32-make output:
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable main.exe
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/kui c++/main/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `InitWindow'
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/kui c++/main/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `SetTargetFPS'
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/kui c++/main/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `WindowShouldClose'
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/kui c++/main/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `BeginDrawing'
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/kui c++/main/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `ClearBackground'
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/kui c++/main/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `DrawText'
C:/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/kui c++/main/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `CloseWindow'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\main.dir\build.make:98: recipe for target 'main.exe' failed        
mingw32-make[2]: *** [main.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main.dir/all' failed   
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:89: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2

I was trying to link and get raylib to work with c++. In a tutorial I found it was recommended to use CMake, however after following the tutorial steps I still got the error messages about undefined references. How to modify the project to get rid of them?

If target_link_libraries(main raylib) is correct, then include_directories(${raylib_SOURCE_DIR}/include) should not be needed, because raylib target already has correct include dirs in the properties. But I'm not sure how FetchContent_MakeAvailable is dealing with these things. What if you simply unpack the raylib zip in your project and add_subdirectory(raylib-5.0) ?

default mingw from sourceforge naah, get mingw from https://www.msys2.org/ , the version you got from other sites is like over 10 years old

In FetchContent_Declare, you can change the link to point to the sources rather than to the released version for the specific platform:
FetchContent_Declare(
    raylib
    URL https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/archive/refs/tags/5.0.zip
)

This of course will cause the raylib library to be compiled along with your project, but from the documentation of FetchContent_Declare I believe that this is the purpose of this command.
Another way would be to simply download the precompiled released version for your platform, install it, and then use find_package CMake call to use it.

doing that started compiling raylib  as you sayed but it threw this conflict error at the end
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:48:0,
                 from C:\Users\admin\Desktop\projects\kui c++\main\build\_deps\raylib-src\src\raudio.c:136:
c:\mingw\include\winuser.h:3519:25: error: conflicting types for 'CloseWindow'
 WINUSERAPI BOOL  WINAPI CloseWindow (HWND);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\admin\Desktop\projects\kui c++\main\build\_deps\raylib-src\src\raudio.c:75:0:

and many like this i dont have space in this comment

@KetsebaotGizachew looks similar to your problem https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/issues/792 , you likely need an updated 64bit version of mingw to compile raylib, get an updated version of mingw from https://www.msys2.org/ , don't forget to uninstall the version you currently have on your system to not end up with conflicts.
